# How do I query the running pg_hba configuration?

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-hba.conf

I want to test if a replication connection is authorized by `pg_hba.conf` on the provider before issuing the replication-starting command, and don't know how. (I have access to both unix and postgresql shells on both nodes)

For the non-replication connection, I would connect `psql` using a connstring like `'host=$MASTER_IP port=5432 dbname=$DATABASE user=$DBUSER password=$DBPASSWORD'`

**Context:**
I am writing a script to automate the setup of replication between servers, and configuration of the servers is managed through different systems/repositories (legacy reasons). Therefore, I want to test if settings are all right at each step.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Version 10 and above

There is a very convenient view for this called [`pg_hba_file_rules`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html).

```sql
table pg_hba_file_rules ;

 line_number │   type    │   database    │  user_name  │  address  │                 netmask                 │ auth_method │ options │ error 
─────────────┼───────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼───────
           3 │ local     │ {all}         │ {all}       │           │                                         │ trust       │         │ 
           4 │ hostssl   │ {all}         │ {+users}    │ 127.0.0.1 │ 255.255.255.255                         │ pam         │         │ 
           5 │ host      │ {all}         │ {all}       │ 127.0.0.1 │ 255.255.255.255                         │ md5         │         │ 
           6 │ hostssl   │ {all}         │ {+users}    │ ::1       │ ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff │ pam         │         │ 
           7 │ host      │ {all}         │ {all}       │ ::1       │ ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff │ md5         │         │ 
           8 │ hostssl   │ {replication} │ {standby}   │ all       │                                         │ md5         │         │ 
           9 │ hostnossl │ {all}         │ {all}       │ all       │                                         │ reject      │         │
```

### Up to version 9.6

For earlier versions, it is a bit cumbersome and error-prone (and works only for superusers, see the notes).

The only built-in way of reading `pg_hba.conf` I can currently imagine is using `pg_read_file()`.

```
SELECT pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf');
```

will return you the whole file, in a single row, which then contains the newline characters (be them whichever flavour your OS likes:

```
[...]
 # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD↵
                                                                       ↵
 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only                  ↵
 local   all             all                                     md5   ↵
 # IPv4 local connections:                                             ↵
 host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5   ↵
[...]
```

You can further process this to your liking.

**Notes:**

- The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) tells us the following:

  > The functions shown in Table 9-86 [*pg_read_file() included - me*] provide native access to files on the machine hosting the server. Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting for log files. Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

  The bit about superusers shouldn't be a problem for you, as you are setting up replication.  If `pg_hba.conf` is not in the mentioned directories, you can add a symlink to it to trick the system:

```
postgres@Z22309: cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
postgres@Z22309:~/9.5/main$ ln -s /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf
```

- All this won't tell you if the file was changed but the config not reloaded.  For this, you have to compare the results of `pg_conf_load_time()` and `pg_stat_file()`, as shown below.  At the same time, you will still don't know exactly which changes were made since the last reload.  Also, as mentioned in a comment, `pg_conf_load_time()` will advance even when loading the file was not successful, leading to confusion - at least I am not aware how one could tell the reloading was successful or not.

```sql
SELECT pg_conf_load_time() > modification FROM pg_stat_file('pg_hba.conf');
```

- In [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203398/6219), I show a way how to split the lines returned above.

Comment: A heads up that `pg_conf_load_time()` will return an updated timestamp even when the reloading of a config file fails. My `pg_hba.conf` had an `hostssl` entry when SSL was not configured so while @dezso's `SELECT ...` statement was showing that postgres had re-read the config file none of my changes in `pg_hba.conf` were being picked up until I removed the `hostssl` entries.