# Get lines of pg_hba.conf with trust method from user with minimal privileges

Tags: postgresql, functions, pg-hba.conf

I try on PostgreSQL 9.3 to get the lines of `pg_hba.conf` where the authentication method is `trust` from user with minimal privileges. I wrote a function, but it doesn't work:

```
create function public.get_pghba_with_trust() 
  returns TABLE (
    TYPE            text
  , DATABASE        text
  , PGUSER            text
  , ADDRESS         text
  , METHOD          text) 
as
$$ 
  SELECT * 
  FROM regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf'),'\n') t(a) 
  WHERE a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$';
$$
language sql
security definer;
```

This returns an error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Final statement returns too few columns.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "get_pghba_with_trust"
```

Grant execute on function

```
grant execute on function get_pghba_with_trust() to redcheck;
```

Try other function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pghba_with_trust() RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  trust text;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO trust from regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf'),'\n') t(a) WHERE a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$';
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'not used';
  ELSE
    RETURN trust;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql security definer;
```

Grant execute on function

```
grant execute on function get_pghba_with_trust() to redcheck;
```

Try run function get_pghba_with_trust

```
SELECT * FROM get_pghba_with_trust();
```

Error:

```
ERROR: must be superuser TO READ files 
CONTEXT: SQL STATEMENT "SELECT * from regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf'),'\n') t(a) WHERE a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$'" PL/pgSQL FUNCTION get_pghba_with_trust() line 5 AT SQL STATEMENT
```

How get lines of pg_hba.conf on PostgreSQL 9.3 with trust method from user with minimal privileges?

Comment: `regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf'),'\n')` returns a single line of text, you should split it again

Comment: Please move your edit to a separate question, as it addresses a totally different problem.

Comment: Hello! Added PostgreSQL 9.3 to question. Sorry, I misspelled the question. So I did make a clarification in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC.list_settings

```
CREATE FUNCTION PUBLIC.list_settings 
  () returns setof pg_catalog.pg_settings 
AS 
  $$ 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_settings; 

  $$ LANGUAGE SQL security definer;
```

Then grant execute on that function to your user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION PUBLIC.list_settings() TO the_user;
```

which then has just to run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   regexp_split_to_table(PUBLIC.list_settings(),'\n') t(a) 
WHERE  a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$';
```

---

### Or other choice

CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_showfile(myfile text) RETURNS text AS $x$
BEGIN
RETURN pg_read_file(myfile, 0, 1000000);
END;
$x$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.f_showfile

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.f_showfile (text) TO the_user;
```

Get lines with trust string from pg_hba.conf

```
SELECT *
FROM regexp_split_to_table(f_showfile('pg_hba.conf'),'\n') t(a)
WHERE a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$';
```

Get lines with primary_conninfo string from recovery.conf

```
SELECT *
FROM regexp_split_to_table(f_showfile('recovery.conf'),'\n') t(a)
WHERE a ~ '^ *primary_conninfo';
```

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there, just have to process the output from `pg_read_file()` as it returns each line of `pg_hba.conf` as a single value.  The following query will do the trick:

```
WITH file (line) AS (
    SELECT regexp_split_to_array(a, '\t+') 
      FROM regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf'), '\n') AS t(a)
     WHERE a ~ '^[^#].*trust\s*$'
)
SELECT line[1] AS type, 
       line[2] AS database, 
       line[3] AS username, 
       CASE WHEN array_length(line, 1) = 4 THEN NULL ELSE line[4] END AS range, 
       CASE WHEN array_length(line, 1) = 4 THEN line[4] ELSE line[5] END AS method
  FROM file;
```

This might not work in all cases that are possible in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), though - you can tweak this query if you need to.

As you already noticed, [`pg_read_file()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) can be run only by superusers.  This is the very reason why you need `SECURITY DEFINER` on your function.  In order to make it work, you have to create the function as a superuser.  (Note that changing owner after a non-superuser created the function doesn't work.  If this is your case, drop the function first an create it anew, as a superuser this time.)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer. I changed quiestion

Comment: @AntonPatsev: please do not change your question or extend the scope of it once you get answers.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the question. So I will make a clarification in the question

Answer (score 2):

Starting with PostgreSQL 10, there's a built-in `pg_hba_file_rules` system view that provides this information. From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html :

> The view **pg_hba_file_rules** provides a summary of the contents of the
>   client authentication configuration file, pg_hba.conf. A row appears
>   in this view for each non-empty, non-comment line in the file, with
>   annotations indicating whether the rule could be applied successfully.
>
> This view can be helpful for checking whether planned changes in the
>   authentication configuration file will work, or for diagnosing a
>   previous failure. Note that this view reports on the current contents
>   of the file, not on what was last loaded by the server.

The permission to read on this view and the underlying function can be granted to a non-superuser:

```
grant execute on function pg_catalog.pg_hba_file_rules() to somerole;
grant select on pg_catalog.pg_hba_file_rules to somerole;
```

which then has just to run:

```
select * from pg_hba_file_rules WHERE auth_method = 'trust';
```

Comment: Hello! Added PostgreSQL 9.3 to question.
Sorry, I misspelled the question. So I did make a clarification in the question